# Representing JSON Document in a XSD

Tags: json, xsd

I am trying to hammer in a json formated document structure into a tool that only accepts it represented as an XSD.

For example:

```
{
    "fields": [
        "Deal State",
        "PTI",
        "LTV",
        "assetpropevercount",
        "evictioncount",
        "inquirynonshortterm12month",
        "addronfilecount"
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            "text",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I can get very close but haven't figured it out completely.  It seems like it should be simple but my lack of experience with XSD(s) in general is stopping me in my tracks.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

And almost as fast as I asked it I got a solution.... from the Risk manager lol...

````
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element maxOccurs="7" minOccurs="7" name="fields" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element maxOccurs="7" minOccurs="7" name="rows" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>```
````